# How to NSLog an Optional Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, nslog, option-type

`NSLog` is still around in Swift, and offers some extras not available with `println` such as the timestamp, module, and thread.

However, I'm unsure how to log an optional, for example an optional `Int`.

Logging an unwrapped optional works fine, e.g.

```
if let i = myIndex 
{
   NSLog("%@ i %d", __FUNCTION__, i)
}
```

Attempting to log `myIndex`, which I would expect to be an object therefore using format specifier `%@`;

```
NSLog("%@ myIndex %@", __FUNCTION__, myIndex)
```

Gives build error:

```
Value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

How can I use `NSLog` - **not println** - to console out my Optional Int?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the string interpolation syntax:

```
let d: Int? = 5

NSLog("\(d)")
```

Comment: was using that however it seems to cause crashes. At least previous to beta 3. Will try it now

Comment: yeah it always compiled OK but sometimes crashed on the NSLog with interpolation

Comment: Couldn't be that same beta crash? I did not experienced that.

Comment: As an alternative you can use: `let i: Int? = 5`
`NSLog("%@", toString(i))`

Comment: Not seeing crashes these days with NSLog string interpolation using Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002), so accepting answer above. Thanks @DánielNagy